# Adding API's to chromium build in Electron framework

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, electron

I would like to write custom functions in Window API in chromium source code. So how do we do it?

In case of doubts about window API here's a link to what I mean [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window). I would like to have custom property functions analogus to those shown in the link.

It's for a github electron project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a week of searching I finally found the solution. Thanks to a pull request by magicae@github.

You need to look create your custom function in

```
electron/atom/browser/api/lib/atom_api_web_contents.cc
```

as say

```
bool WebContents::GetOkOk() {
  return true;
}
```

And define the same in it'h header file

```
electron/atom/browser/api/lib/atom_api_web_contents.h
```

as

```
bool GetOkOk();
```

Lastly you need to export the function through the webContents method located in

```
electron/atom/renderer/lib/web-view/web-view.js
```

as

```
/* Public-facing API methods. - modified by Akshay Thakare */
  methods = ['getOk','getURL', ... ];
```

And you are good to go.

Finally after you compile your electron app,

in the main.js file add,

```
console.log(mainWindow.webContents.getOk());
```

and your done.

Answer (score 0):

As JS is prototype oriented, you could simply extend the `BrowserWindow` API

```
var BrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow; // main process
var BrowserWindow = require('electron').remote.BrowserWindow; // renderer process

BrowserWindow.foo = function() {
    console.log('foo');
}
```

Not sure if you're looking for someting more specific, but I'm not sure you can extend it with heavy impacts on the system, could you explain exactly what you are trying to do ?

Comment: I want to embed that BrowserWindow.foo into the chromium source code so that its not visible to the user

Comment: You are using Electron, so except if you open devTools, there is now way for users to get variables from console. Also, if you really want to extend the API under the hood, the only way would be to fork Electron and add  you own methods, then rebuild it.

Comment: Electron main process source code is not compiled anyone can open it up and read. Which is why I have already forked libchromium but I am unable to figure out how to embed my methods into it.

Comment: In my opinion, you're doing things the hard way. I see no problem extending the API in pure JS in the main process as it's not accessible by anyone.

Comment: Yes but those are symmetric encryption keys which cannot be kept open

Comment: Ohw, you may be interested by this issue on Github so: https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/3041. Maybe take a look at these too: http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/09/12/securing-api-keys-in-a-client-side-javascript-app/

Comment: I am aware of the method you have suggested but it does not fit my use case. I need to modify chromium source code

Comment: I need to access the keys using BrowserWindow.key so its not isolated. I will try to frame a better question

Comment: btw, you may find better advices here: http://discuss.atom.io. The Electron developers will probably give you better answers.

Comment: I will give that a try. Thanks :)